# php redirect and querystring

Tags: php, redirect, query-string, location

i have script

```
    <?php
$to = $_GET["to"];

header("Location: $to");
?>
```

if i call script such

```
out.php?to=http://site.ru/page.php?param1=1&param2=2
```

in param $to be only `http://site.ru/page.php?param1=1&`

how to fix? i want that `$to = http://site.ru/page.php?param1=1&param2=2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$to must be [urlencoded](http://php.net/urlancode), but note that you giving a redirect script to anyone, so, any phisher can use it.
So, it would be better to store urls in the database and pass only an identifier.

Answer (score 2):

You can escape the URL at the site calling `out.php`:

```
<a href="out.php?to=<?PHP echo htmlspecialchars(urlencode($to)); ?>">Go to $to</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

`&` is a reserved character in an [URI](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt). When you access this URL, `&param2=2`
 is interpreted as belonging to the current URL and **not** to the value of `to`.
If you want to transmit it literally, you have to [encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) it with `%26`:

```
http://site.ru/page.php?param1=1%26param2=2
```

Most programming languages provide a function to do so. (e.g. [JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp), [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)). The best thing is to encode the whole URL.

Answer (score 0):

try encoding the to URL in base64 and then in the example that u have shown decode it before you pass it to the header :)

Answer (score 0):

urlencode it

```
urlencode($to)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem before, this is what I did:

```
$arr=explode('?to=',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],2);
$new_to=$arr[1];
```

Now you can use the $new_to variable.
Of course if you're using this for production environment, I would recommend encoding the url as the other answers advised. I was using it for testing curl script. getting the variable this way has lots of flaws, so be careful.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a Function called "html_entity_decode"

[Click Here for more information about this function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

or use **md5** function to encrypt the URL and then decrypt it when you put it into a varriable.

I hope this can help you

Comment: md5 is a hash function. You normally cannot retrieve the original value from a hash (but md5 is broken anyway ;)) Also the method you linked to is to encode special characters in **HTML** to HTML entities. This is very different from encoding characters in an URL.